# SSR warnings when trying to load parts of the main app layout based on the current session

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an admin dashboard built with Next.Js. Basically, I want to do something like this:

- User logs in from the `/login` route
- While processing the login, show a loading screen
- In the `/` route, if the user exist, it will load the app or if the user is missing, redirect back to login

I'm trying to do it like this:

`_app.js`:

```
...
<Head>
  <title>My App</title>
</Head>

<ApolloProvider>
  <AppLayout>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </AppLayout>
</ApolloProvider>
...
```

`AppLayout.js`:

```
...
// If there's no user and we are not in any of the session routes (login or forgot-password), redirect the user to login
useEffect(() => {
  if (!(user.id) && !(router.pathname === '/login' || router.pathname === '/forgot-password')) {
    Router.push('/login').then();
  }
});

// While the user login process is happening, show a loading screen.
if (
  isLoading ||
  ((user.id) && (router.pathname === '/login' || router.pathname === '/forgot-password'))
) {
  return <Loading />;
}

// If the user is there, show the admin panel
if (user.id) {
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar />

      <Layout>
        <TopMenu />

        {children}
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}

// If no user and we are in the session routes, show the session forms without the main app layout
if (router.pathname === '/login' || router.pathname === '/forgot-password') {
  return <>{children}</>;
}

// For everything else, show an empty div
return <div />;
...
```

Now this works. User logs in and the app loads. If not loged in, you can't go to the app. But the user is there only in the front end. Stored in a global state (Managed by Mobx). The page it loads in the server is different from the page it loads in the browser. Because of this, the app throws errors like this:

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <section> in <section>
```

So my question is, how to handle situations like this without breaking Next.Js? Since we are dealing with the `_app.js` file, breaking this can disable SSR for the whole app right?

Comment: Which line did you get that warning?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store some kind of id of the use in a place which will be accessible for both ends, client & server.

One common option is to store it in JWT in a cookie, and make a "auth" request on both side with this token, if logged in, the "auth" request will return the user details, other wise redirects.

In my app, I've "disabled" the SSR of my admin app, because there is no need for SEO for it.